# Rate parameter in Weibull distribution

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution

I use well known parameter estimation methods to estimate `scale` and `shape` parameters the Weibull. By the end I have a good estimation `reliability function`.

I have `failure rate` that change over time of my items. Can I use the `failure rate as shape or scale` parameter in my weibull function.

I tried to use the `failure rate` instead of the `shape`, and I still have good `reliability function`.

Many articles use failure rate as `λ` the rate parameter in exponential distribution

Comment: @jbowman, got the purpose of question, it is basically clear and very simple. Can I use failure rate as parameter in Weibull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use the shape or scale parameter as a failure rate.  The failure rate is a well-defined mathematical function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate for a definition.

For the three-parameter Weibull distribution with centrality parameter $\gamma$, scale parameter $\eta$, and shape parameter $\beta$, the failure rate function is:

$$\lambda(T) = \frac{\beta}{\eta}\left(\frac{T-\gamma}{\eta}\right)^{\beta-1}$$

where $T$ is the time at which we are evaluating the failure rate.  You could simply plug your parameter estimates into this equation and use the result to estimate the failure rate at various times $T$.

Comment: Yes, this what I thought. Until I see some articles use failure rate as lambda in exponential distribution. Is it okay in distribution that have constant failure rate.

Comment: The parameter of the Exponential distribution *is* the failure rate (or the inverse of same, depending upon the parameterization)  of the exponential distribution. Try plugging $\beta = 1, \gamma = 0$ into the above formula; those two parameter values turn a Weibull distribution into an Exponential distribution.  You will see the failure rate function is just $1/\eta$.   Also - there is only one distribution that has a constant failure rate, and that's the Exponential.

Comment: Okay thank you @Jbowman, what is rate parameter in Weibull and Exponential.

Comment: I just gave you the formula above, that's what the answer to the question was.  I explained what the rate for the Exponential distribution is in my comment.